# using a div inside a td tag

Tags: html, css

i want a code which displays as
 Account No:
[image]

But in my code its displayed as[image]

and my code is as below

```
<td colspan="3">Account No:<div class="boxed">

        </div>
   <div class="boxed">

     </div>
   <div class="boxed">

   </div>
    <div class="boxed">

    </div>
   <div class="boxed">

  </div>
  </td>
```

Comment: What is the style of `.boxed`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose the `Account No.` text with a div and add

`CSS "float:left"`

To that div.

Working code:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" style="float: left;">
        <div style="float: left">Account No:</div>
        <div class="boxed"></div>
        <div class="boxed"></div>
        <div class="boxed"></div>
        <div class="boxed"></div>
        <div class="boxed"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<style>
.boxed {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `div` to wrap them and `float`.

```
<td colspan="3">
    <div style="float:left;padding:15px 5px 0 0;">Account No:</div>
    <div style="float:right;">
        <div class="boxed"></div>
        <div class="boxed"></div>
        <div class="boxed"></div>
        <div class="boxed"></div>
        <div class="boxed"></div>
    </div>
</td>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d57d1mbr/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this html structure and see fiddle link as below:

```
<td colspan="3">
<div class="title">
Account No:
</div>
<div class="boxed">
1
        </div>
   <div class="boxed">
2
     </div>
   <div class="boxed">
3
   </div>
    <div class="boxed">
4
    </div>
   <div class="boxed">
5
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.title {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}
.boxed {
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 7%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wwta4e8h/

Answer (score 1):

```css
.box{
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div style="float: left;">
        <div style="float: left;padding-top:10px;padding-right:10px">Account No:</div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace float: left; with display: inline-block; And in case if you want the boxes to ne top aligned add  vertical-align: top;

```
 <style>
     .boxed {
         border: 1px solid black;
         display: inline-block;
         vertical-align: top; 
         width:30px;
         height:30px;
    } 
</style>
```